# FB Like button stopped counting, strange behavior

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I've a problem with the "Like Button" in my website from a few days ago.

Everything worked properly but suddenly the counter stopped working on reching the "11,045 likes", and the strangest thing is that when I logged into my Facebook account, the counter shows 11.048 likes, and being logged out, it returns to 11.045, but this never gets up that number.

I've tested it and when you click everything works correctly, the counter adds one, and the site is published in the FB user's wall, but when the page is reloaded the likes counter returns to 11,045.

I have read a lot on different forums and almost all documentation of Facebook but I can't find a solution.

I've tried with the "**Open Graph Debugger**" (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and everything seems to work correctly, so I do not know what else to do.

The URL with the problem is: http://bit.ly/UctC7d
FB Debug: http://bit.ly/RkQNLP
*(I've shortened the urls for privacy)*

Thanks in advance!
Daniel

Comment: What do you mean, the counter stopped working? On your site I see “11k” likes displayed … if you want the exact number, then you have to go with the standard like button layout.

Comment: Hi CBroe, Yes, the counter displays 11k, or if you see the exact number 11.045 / 11.048 likes (depending on if you are logged or not in FB), but stopped at that number weeks ago. And checking the insights of the website on Facebook, I can see that there are new "likes" or "shares" every day, but these do not add up to counter widget, that is fixed on "11.045 / 11.048 likes".